Contact appears in "recents" but not in "contacts"
iPhone 13, iOS 17.06
The contact C does not appear when I search for it in the "phone" app by selecting "contacts" and typing "C" in the "search".
When I look at "recents" a call to C appears with her NAME not just number.
Why does C's name appear in the recents even though it's not in my "phone" app's contacts? Shouldn't it be just the number?
